# Too slow reading CSV from HDFS into Pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs

I have developed a Spark-HDFS cluster with (5 workers and 5 datanodes) apart from the corresponding Spark master and Namenode.

I'm programming in pyspark using the Jupyter Notebook which is initialized with `--executor-memory 30G --driver-memory 20G`. 
The problem comes when i try to load a 348MB csv file from my HDFS into a pyspark DataFrame that it takes aprox. 15s

I think that it's quite a lot of time for this small file. The code I'm using is:

```
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df1 = sqlContext.read.load("hdfs://namenode:8020/user/***/*****.csv", format='com.databricks.spark.csv',
header='true',
sep=';',
inferSchema='true')
```

I've considered to load it into a RDD but since DataFrames are developed for this I think it fits better. Moreover, after loading this CSV I have to join another CSV which is just a column (20MB).

Comment: No, but i think that is a bit tricky cause all the data provided by the client is given in csv files and by the moment are "small" files but if we have to make a copy of each into JSON would reduce our HDFS capacity considerably.

Comment: I checked but my premise was untrue: csv has a C based parser, so that would not help (much) anyway